# Strange tiles with gdal2tiles

Tags: gdal2tiles

When I run gdal2tiles with this command I get tiles that look like the one below. The Tiff-file is fine, it shows fine in Qgis. The image is 7560x14517 pixels. I tried to scale down the image to 2000x3840 pixel and the it worked as expected.

```
gdal2tiles -w none -p raster -z 0-6 -s EPSG:3857 "C:\inprogress\warped_18_rotated_1620743705845.tiff" "C:\temp"
```

Is there some top limit in how many pixels the image can have in gdal2tiles? Or am I missing some argument that could fix this type of problem?

[image: tiles]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly happens but there is a bug report about that here https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/1980.

Try if playing with the -z parameter helps.